# Python package for (adaptive) function plotting

Tags: python, plotting

Are there any mature Python packages that can plot *functions*, and possibly use adaptive sampling?

I am looking to pass only a function (can be a numerical black box) and a range, and expect a plot as the output.

What I am *not* looking for: manually generating the sampling points, manually computing the function values, and finally plotting these *pre-computed* values.  I know matplotlib can do this.

Comment: Looking for something like MATLAB `ezplot`, Mathematica `Plot`, etc.  I'm new to using Python like this.  I'm interested in ready made libraries, not writing an adaptive sampler myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want the [multi-precision plot function from SymPy](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/mpmath/plotting.html), which is capable of plotting arbitrary black-box functions over a given range.

```
import math
from sympy.mpmath import plot
plot(lambda x: math.exp(x), [1, 4])
```

[image: exponential plot]

Comment: Looks like exactly what I was looking for.  Are you aware of other packages that have this functionality?

Comment: Geoff mentioned Sage.  Nothing else is on my radar.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

- [Sage can plot functions adaptively](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/plot3d/sage/plot/plot3d/plot3d.html); the link is to a 3d implementation, but presumably, there is an analogous 2d implementation.
- You could use [this function that samples adaptively 1-d functions](http://scipy-central.org/item/53/1/adaptive-sampling-of-1d-functions). (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084634/adaptive-plotting-of-a-function-in-python for discussion) Judging from your comments, this may not be a solution you want, but presumably, if you can do all of the steps individually, cobbling together a convenience wrapper with the interface you want would not take too long.
- [SymPy has an adaptive plotting interface](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/plotting.html) included; it appears to only plot SymPy expressions, though, which may not suit your needs. (Ondrej can correct me on this point.)

These implementations probably span the extremes of heavyweight (Sage is a big library) and lightweight (a single sampling function is not intrusive, and presumably, you could use it with any graphics backend you like).

Comment: Is it possible to just use the plotting part of Sage without having to get the whole huge system?  I know how to implement a 1D adaptive plotter, [I once spent a considerable amount of time thinking about this](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/923/605).  But this time I was just looking for a readymade solution.

Comment: You could probably selectively import just the plotting functions you need using the `from ... import ...` syntax (e.g., `from sage.plot import plot3d`), but you'd still have to install the whole library. If GPL'd code isn't an issue, you could also look at the source and pull out ready-made parts you need. I figured you know how to do it based on answers to other questions, and I'm a little surprised this feature isn't already part of matplotlib.

Comment: Do you often use Python yourself for this type of work?  Do you think that your answer is mostly exhaustive?  If yes, I'll accept now instead of waiting for more.

Comment: I do. I use Python ~40% of the time, but I'm not always up-to-date on cutting edge Python, because I use it on a piecemeal basis for work projects, and the occasional side project. Most of the Python updates I get, I hear through the grapevine from serious Pythonistas like Aron Ahmadia (one of the lead PyClaw devs), Ondrej Certik (started SymPy, big Cython contributor), William Stein (founded Sage, SageMathCloud), and Andy Terrel (worked on FEniCS, now works at Continuum). People of that caliber would know more than I about this topic, so this answer probably covers 80% of what's out there.

Comment: Oooh, now I'm a serious Pythonista? :)